# Обработка редюсеров в Redux

Tags: javascript, redux

У меня есть массив объектов, мне нужно менять active на true в каждом объекте по индексу.

Есть массив:

```
transplantation: [
    {
      stops: 'all',
      label: 'Все',
      active: false
    },
    {
      stops: 0,
      label: 'Без пересадок',
      active: true
    },
    {
      stops: 1,
      label: '1 пересадка',
      active: false
    },
    {
      stops: 2,
      label: '2 пересадки',
      active: false
    },
    {
      stops: 3,
      label: '3 пересадки',
      active: false
    }
  ]
```

Есть попытка:

```
case ON_SHOW:
    return {
        ...state, 
        transplantation: [...state.transplantation, state.transplantation[action.index].active = true]
    }
```

Хоть значение изменить и получается, однако создается лишний div. Как правильно обработать массив?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неверно понимаете 
`[...state.transplantation, state.transplantation[action.index].active = true]`

Это означает создать новый массив с элементами массива `state.transplantation` и элементом `state.transplantation[action.index].active = true`, поэтому у вас добавляется каждый раз новый элемент ( так как вы в массив новый элемент добавляете )

Можете сделать вот так:

```
case ON_SHOW:
return {
    ...state, 
    transplantation: state.transplantation.map((el, i) => {
        if (i === action.index) {
            el = {...el, active: true}
        }
        return el
    })
}
```